# Losses in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Can anyone kindly explain what basically classification loss and localization loss mean in `tensorflow`?

I am getting this losses during SSD training procedure using `tensorflow` API but not understanding both of this two losses at all.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111847/tensorflow-object-detection-api-what-do-the-losses-mean-in-the-object-detectio) I read that localization loss is the loss of the Bounding Box regressor which arises a new question and that is what is bounding box regressor?

Can anyone brief it please?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps, I tried to give a brief explanation as I understand it.

> what basically classification loss and localization loss mean in tensorflow?

classification /localisation loss values are the result of loss functions and represent the "price paid for inaccuracy of predictions" in the classification/localisation problems (respectively).

The loss value given is a sum of the classification loss and the localisation loss.
The optimisation algorithms are trying to reduce these loss values until your loss sum reaches a point where you are happy with the results and consider your network 'trained'.

You can generally think of loss as a score where 'lower score equals better model'.

> what is bounding box regressor?

The bounding box regressor is a trained model to obtain a more accurate bounding box in relation to the ROI in image classification problems I believe.