# How to interpret TensorBoard loss graph?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, object-detection-api

[TensorBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyzNk.png)

I'm using Tensorflow API for object detection and here is the loss plot from its default settings. Can you help me interpret differences of `classification_loss`, `localization_loss` and `objectness_loss`? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111847/tensorflow-object-detection-api-what-do-the-losses-mean-in-the-object-detectio

Comment: Guess your are working with Region Proposal Network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could calculate the location loss like this:

```
def location_loss( x, y, width, height, l_x, l_y, l_width, l_height, alpha = 0.001 ):
    point_loss = ( tf.square( l_x - x ) + tf.square( l_y - y ) ) * alpha
    size_loss = ( tf.square( tf.sqrt( l_width ) - tf.sqrt( width ) ) + tf.square( tf.sqrt( l_height ) - tf.sqrt( height ) ) ) * alpha
    location_loss = point_loss + size_loss
    return location_loss
```

These losses you mentioned are not part of the TensorBoard. There is another TensorBoard plugin you should check the source code and the definitions for these.