# Which losses scalar shoud I watch in tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorboard, object-detection-api

I'm training my custom object detection model that only detects person.
I followed [this github document](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10).
Here is my environment.

```
Tensorflow version : 1.13.1 GPU
Tensorboard version : 1.13.1
Pre-trained model : SSD mobilenet v2 quantized 300x300 coco
```

According to above document, my model's loss should drop down under 2.
So I opened tensorboard and found classification losses, total losses, clone losses scalars.
[Here is my tensorboard snapshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SgaV.png)
Which losses scalars should I look up?
I also have problem with converging.
My model's loss converged at 4, not 2.
How can I fix it?
I reduced the learning rate 0.004(provided value) to 0.0000095.
But it still converged at 4.
Here is my train_config.

```
train_config: {
  batch_size: 6
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0000095
          decay_steps: 500
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
```

Is there anything to change?
Thanks for all help.

Comment: Can you add a snapshot of the Tensorboard graphs?

Comment: @AniketBote Thanks for help! I added new image link above

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111847/tensorflow-object-detection-api-what-do-the-losses-mean-in-the-object-detectio) answer your question.

Comment: @AniketBote Than, classfication loss is what I should look up? Thanks. And I have 1 more questions. I added 1 more problem on this post. Can you check that problem too?